# Update class after animation

Tags: jquery

I have the following function:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    $("#em")
    .animate(
    { left: -15 }, {
        duration: "slow",
        easing: "easeOutBack"
    })
    .animate(
    { left: -315 }, {
        duration: "slow",
        easing: "easeOutBack"
    });                         
}, 2000);
```

and I would like to changed the class on another element after the animation is complete

```
$('.flip').removeClass('ui-icon-carat-1-w').addClass('ui-icon-carat-1-e');
```

How do I tie those two together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) can accept a callback as its last argument; if you provide a function for it, the function will be executed when the animation has completed.

When using the alternative syntax with options as an object, provide the callback using the key `"complete"`. So you 'd have:

```
$("#em")
.animate(
{ left: -15 }, {
    duration: "slow",
    easing: "easeOutBack",
    complete: function() {
       $('.flip').removeClass('ui-icon-carat-1-w').addClass('ui-icon-carat-1-e');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `animate()` method accepts a callback that will run after the animation finishes.